# XSL evaluate attribute with variables

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, expression, evaluate

I would like to use an xsl file to show and evaluate an xml file. The XML file contains an amount of parts which have a title, description, image and an amount. But this amount is dependant on some variables that I will declare in the XSL file. But in this case I have to calculate the expression from within the XML in the XSL file. Is there a way to this?

See example: (the expressions in @amount should be evaluated with the variables from the XML)

XML:

```
<partslist>         
<part value="1" amount="$variable1" visible="true">     
    <title> 
        <nl>Onderdeel 1</nl>
        <fr>Partie 1</fr>
        <en>Part 1</en>
        <de>Teil 1</de>
    </title>    
    <image src="images/partslist/part1.jpg"/>   
</part>     
<part value="2" amount="$variable1 * $variable2" visible="true">        
    <title> 
        <nl>Onderdeel 2</nl>
        <fr>Partie 2</fr>
        <en>Part 2</en>
        <de>Teil 2</de>
    </title>    
    <image src="images/partslist/part2.jpg"/>   
</part> 
<part value="3" amount="$variable3" visible="true">     
    <title> 
        <nl>Onderdeel 3</nl>
        <fr>Partie 3</fr>
        <en>Part 3</en>
        <de>Teil 3</de>
    </title>    
    <image src="images/partslist/part3.jpg"/>   
</part> 
<part value="4" amount="$variable1 + $variable3" visible="true">        
    <title> 
        <nl>Onderdeel 4</nl>
        <fr>Partie 4</fr>
        <en>Part 4</en>
        <de>Teil 4</de>
    </title>    
    <image src="images/partslist/part4.jpg"/>   
</part> 
</partslist>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="1" />
            <xsl:variable name="variable2" select="2" />
            <xsl:variable name="variable3" select="3" />

            <div class="np">
                <H2>Parts List</H2>
                <table border ="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:15%;">ID</th>
                        <th style="width:15%;">Amount</th>
                        <th style="width:40%;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width:30%;">Image</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="partslist/part">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@amount"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title/nl"/></td>
                            <td><img style="width:100%;" src="{image/@src}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you make it clear exactly where your attempt is not working?

Comment: I think you have to create your own calcul eval function on the same principle than Dimitre answer here for xpath eval : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321553/xslt-interpret-a-text-nodes-value-as-xpath-query-and-use-it-in-transformati#7328577

Comment: @Spangen I would like to have the result in the 'amount' column to be the evaluated expression of the expression that is in the XML, but that is not working. (For example the first column should be 'value = 1, amount = 1 (because variable1 = 1), title = Onderdeel1, image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an XSLT processor like Xalan interpreter which supports the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate` function (http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html) then you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic" exclude-result-prefixes="dyn">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="1" />
            <xsl:variable name="variable2" select="2" />
            <xsl:variable name="variable3" select="3" />

            <div class="np">
                <H2>Parts List</H2>
                <table border ="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:15%;">ID</th>
                        <th style="width:15%;">Amount</th>
                        <th style="width:40%;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width:30%;">Image</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="partslist/part">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate(@amount)"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title/nl"/></td>
                            <td><img style="width:100%;" src="{image/@src}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/948Fn5d.

Depending on your XSLT processor, even is there is no support for `dyn:evaluate`, you might be able to implement the functionality with an extension function.

Or move to an XSLT 3 processor that supports `xsl:evaluate`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="1"/>
                <xsl:variable name="variable2" select="2"/>
                <xsl:variable name="variable3" select="3"/>

                <div class="np">
                    <H2>Parts List</H2>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:15%;">ID</th>
                            <th style="width:15%;">Amount</th>
                            <th style="width:40%;">Description</th>
                            <th style="width:30%;">Image</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="partslist/part">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:evaluate xpath="@amount" context-item="."
                                        with-params="
                                            map {
                                                xs:QName('variable1'): $variable1,
                                                xs:QName('variable2'): $variable2,
                                                xs:QName('variable3'): $variable3
                                            }"
                                    />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="title/nl"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img style="width:100%;" src="{image/@src}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate reply, one thing isn't really clear to me;

"Depending on your XSLT processor, even is there is no support for dyn:evaluate, you might be able to implement the functionality with an extension function."

How can I implement this functionality exactly?

Comment: Which XSLT processor exactly on which platform do you use? Some provide the ability to call into the programming language or framework they are implemented with, for instance  `XslCompiledTransform` can use C# or VB.NET to call https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.evaluate(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: I am indeed using XslCompiledTransform in C#. But how do I call the evaluate method in this case? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In general, to call into C# from your XSLT 1 stylesheet executed with XslCompiledTransform, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/extending-xslt-style-sheets.

Comment: Whether it is possible to evaluate an expression containing variables from your XSLT I am not sure, it might need some heavy lifting around XsltContext or it might not be possible. There is still a project https://mvpxml.codeplex.com/ which has source code for many EXSLT functions for XslCompiledTransform, but they don't implement the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate` there, only dyn2:evaluate with no variables support.

Comment: I am not sure whether they did implement their own version of  a `evaluate` extension function because the complex requirements of EXSLT's `dyn:evaluate` are not possible with `XslCompiledTransform` or whether the authors of that library simply did not want to implement the EXSLT version.

Comment: And would it be possible if the variables aren't 'declared' in the XSLT, but if these variables are declared in my C# project?

Comment: Please study the options on extension function and extension objects https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/extending-xslt-style-sheets I linked to, then I am sure you can answer the last question yourself.